# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property ANGULAR6

Tags: html, angular, ngfor

i got an Error while constructing my form (the submission date is almost due, maybe  to much of a panic).`

i recive this error on my google DevConsole, but the page loads perfectly as i want it.

```
`ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'answers' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (QuestionsComponent.html:20)
```

my html

```
              <div class="custom-control custom-radio" *ngFor="let question of question.answers">
                  <input  type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="answers" name="groupOfRadios">
                  <label  class="custom-control-label" for="answers">{{question.body}}</label>
              </div>
```

my TS

```
export class QuestionsComponent implements OnInit {

  //define variables to use
    private question : {
      id: number;
      body: string;
      answers: {
        id: number;
        body: string;
      }[]
    }

  constructor(private router: Router, private http: HttpClient, private quest: QuestionService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.quest.getQuestion().subscribe(
      data=> {
        this.question = {
            id: data.question.id,
            body: data.question.body,
            answers: data.question.answers
            }
          }
    )
    }
  }
```

i want to load a question via server by sending json resp with the data.

answers is an array of ids and bodys belongs to the question.

Sorry and Thank you for your patience.

Best Wishes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the markup first check if your `question` received a data then iterate over it. 
Use safe property accessor - `question?`.

```
<div class="custom-control custom-radio" *ngFor="let question of question?.answers">
    <input  type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="answers" name="groupOfRadios">
    <label  class="custom-control-label" for="answers">{{question.body}}</label>
</div>
```

Or just initialize your variable with empty array of answers

```
private question: {
    id: number;
    body: string;
    answers: {
        id: number;
        body: string;
    }[]
} = {
   id: 0,
   body: null,
   answers: []
}
```

Comment: Thanks! worked like a charm, im still new in angular field. will do my best to get better!

Comment: any idea why my selector group is bounded on selecting only the first radio button? same id?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `*ngIf="question"` so this HTML part will render only once you have data in `question` object until HTTP call is completed.

```
<div *ngIf="question" class="custom-control custom-radio" *ngFor="let question of question.answers">
  <input  type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="answers" name="groupOfRadios">
  <label  class="custom-control-label" for="answers">{{question.body}}</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! worked like a charm, im still new in angular field. will do my best to get better!

Comment: got less then 15 reputation points. my upvote is noted but will not show. im new here :)